# SQL Buffer Pool and Plan cache

Tags: sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, plan-cache, buffer-pool

Does SQL Buffer Pool size = Max server memory.?
I have been trying to find out the reason why plan cache  in my SQL server 2016 gets cleared every few hours.

- I have 128 GB Physical Memory.
- Earlier i kept 126 GB as Max Server memory.
- Only one SQL server instance and a main DB of size 1.5 TB
- Plan cache was getting cleared and i know that nobody is running any
  script to clear plan cache.

I always thought and still think that having 128 GB Physical memory won't cause memory pressure as i think it is more than enough for the application.

Clearing plan cache is causing my slow down in my application.I believe as plan reuse i not happening and bad plans are getting into the plan cache for some queries.

I checked ring buffer for memory pressure and there was indication of low physical memory.

[image: See below]

So i changed Max Server memory to 102 GB and still after changing also i see `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW`

I am confused where Plan cache is allocated.

I learned from [plan cache internals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293624.aspx) that there are four types of caches stores and most of the stored procs,Adhoc queries etc are handles separately and sp_executesql queries are handles separately.
Is there any clues there because most of my queries(90%) are sp_executesql type
Any insights?

Result of querying `select * from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks order by pages_kb desc`

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the queries for any missing indexes? Officially I think lock pages in memory is a no no now, but on physical servers with HP drivers I've seen it work miracles so that drivers and other vendor software doesn't clear the memory. Check for memory messages in your SQL log

Comment: Based on your last statement, I'd dig into the sp_executesql statements. [Check out this question and answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47283/when-does-sp-executesql-refresh-the-query-plan) specifically about the variables your statements may be using. Perhaps it's simply the underlying queries themselves.

Comment: @Alen : i checked for messages in SQL error log,but there is none regarding cache clearing.There are no missing indexes ,i checked those as well.

Comment: what about memory being pooled out? and check for missing indexes too

Comment: how do i find memory pooled out?I checked the `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks` and the results are updated in the post.Can you address whether Buffer Pool size = Max server memory? and whether plan cache comes in this buffer pool.

Comment: can you run [sp_blitz](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_Blitz.sql) with `@OutputType ='MARKDOWN', @CheckProcedureCache=1` and post the output here in your question.

Comment: Side note: Have you considered using the query store?

Comment: i have tried using query store.I tried forcing query plans to slow queries ,but it didn't help,probably because the plan cache is getting cleared.

Comment: @scsimon The post you referred  will infer that sp_executesql is not a bad option and sql server should reuse plan from sp_executesql queries.Also i have set parameterization as forced.

Comment: Correct @user9516827 I didnt mean to come off as if it was bad, but that you parameters could cause plan inflation. Your comment refutes this though.